# iOS: App doesn't work after a while (parallel installation of Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I used XCode 7.3 for a long time and have developed a game for my wife. Today when recompiling and starting it on the iPhone I get an error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/797B62E4-4355-4FA7-A56A-90633DF2E16D/Dirks Letter Puzzle.app/Dirks Letter Puzzle
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/797B62E4-4355-4FA7-A56A-90633DF2E16D/Dirks Letter Puzzle.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/797B62E4-4355-4FA7-A56A-90633DF2E16D/Dirks Letter Puzzle.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
```

I don't have any idea what it means. It ran fine for month (after updating signing). Meanwhile I installed XCode 8 as a separate App to keep 7.3 for this app. I never changed or updated my little game. So sources are still the same. The iPhone is the same. What happend and how can I get it back to run?

Comment: 1) Make sure only one of the Xcodes is open at a time. 2) Do a clean (command shift k), and clean the build folder (option command shift k). now if you run your app do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes this fixed it. Thanks a lot (also from my wife ;-) )

Comment: great! glad it worked! :) added this comment as an answer so you can accept it and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*posting this answer from my comment*

> 1) Make sure only one of the Xcodes is open at a time.
>
> 2) Do a clean (command shift k), and clean the build folder (option
>   command shift k).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, it tell you cannot find  resource Like image Vide music in the Application. You can try this:

Check that you have a resource, if not - then can add it.

[image: Screenshot]

I hope it can help you.